# How can i add specific values in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, math

Sorry if this is a trivial problem - i'm very new to java

given an array e.g. `double[] numbers = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` how can you sum specific numbers given
e.g.

```
for(numbers >4)
sum numbers;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 or later, try `Arrays.stream(numbers).sum();`. This is a stream API example which is quiet faster. Another way is to iterate using a for loop like this

```
int sum = 0;
for (Double num: numbers) {
    if (num > 4) {
        sum += num;
    }
}
```

Comment: you forget the condition of only counting the numbers greater than 4

Comment: Edited the answer as per your requirements. Please accept the answer if this is what you need

Comment: yeah, I'm just browsing this questionpage Anchit, but please try to read it as well. He wants to sum up all numbers within the array that are greater than 4. Your if-check only does something if there are more than 4 numbers in the array. Perhaps move your check inside the for-loop?

Comment: something like this @Paul?

Comment: That's it! Minor tip, use the primitive ```double``` or else the array would have to be filtered for ```null```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a for loop

```
double sum =0;
for(int j=0; j<array.length;j++){
double temp = numbers[j];
if(temp>4){ sum+=temp;}
```

The for loop checks each element of the array and adds it to a temporary variable which will be added to sum if it's greater than 4.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two parts here, conditionals, and summing.

Since you're new to java, I'll stick with the most basic form for each:

For the *conditional* part, you can use `if` to see if a number meets a certain criterion:

```java
if (number > 4.0d) {
    // Do something in here.
}
```

For summing, you can simply add to a local variable as you go:

```java
double sum = 0.0d;
for (double number : numbers) {
    sum += number;
}
// After the loop, 'sum' now has the sum of the numbers.
```

So combining these, you can do:

```java
double sum = 0.0d;
for (double number : numbers) {
    if (number > 4.0d) {
        sum += number;
    }
}
// 'sum' now contains the sum of all numbers greater than 4.0
```

---

If I was actually given this problem, chances are I would just do

`Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(n -> n > 4.0d).sum();`

But that's probably not too helpful if you're new to coding/java.

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] numbers = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        
        // classic loop
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > 4){
                sum += numbers[i];
            }
        }
        
        // streams (Java 8 or newer)
        double sum = Arrays.stream(numbers)
                .filter(number -> number > 4)
                .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to calculate the sum of specific numbers, include an `if` condition in the `for` loop as shown below. This will calculate sum of all numbers `>` 4.

```
double[] numbers = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
double sum = 0;
for(double num : numbers) {
    if(num > 4) 
        sum += num;
}
```

**Output:** `18.0`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.  Stream the numbers, filter for > 4 and sum them.

```
double[] numbers = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
 
double sum = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(a->a > 4).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

Prints

```
18
```

Or more tranditionally.

```
double sum = 0;
for (double d : numbers) {
    if (d > 4) {
      sum += d;
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```